# NSDate Next day after midnight

Tags: nsdate

I've got a very simple case, but for some reason I can't find the right way to deal with it because of my "starter" level in iDev. 
User during using my app will have some limits for a one day. I set the limit in NSUserDefaults after a certain count of user actions. 
For now I think it should be NSDate value, but I'm not sure.
 Each time user requests some action, app has to check if there is no limit. How to check it correctly? 
For example, today at 9:00 AM user went out of limit and app has to restrict any actions during midnight. The next day at 0:01 AM after checking limit it has to be "green".

A little bit confusing, I know :(

Comment: were have you been stuck during trying to compare two dates?

Comment: @holex problem is in creating NSDate according to current time. E.g.: now it's 08/19/2016 01:38AM and I need to create NSDate 08/20/2016 00:01 AM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in Swift. The function sets the time to the first minute of the next day, using the NSDateComponents class:

```
public class func getTomorrow() -> NSDate {
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let today = NSDate()
    let dateComp = cal.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: today)
    dateComp.day = dateComp.day + 1
    dateComp.hour = 0
    dateComp.minute = 1
    dateComp.second = 0
    return cal.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!
}
```

I haven't checked if it compiles, but it should be fine.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

To get the start of next day, you can use NSCalendar class with 2 APIs:

First: get next day of your current time (NSDate):

> Returns a new NSDate object representing the absolute time
>   calculated by adding given components to a given date.

```
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingComponents:(NSDateComponents *)comps
                            toDate:(NSDate *)date
                           options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts
```

your `comps` parameter should have only `Day` value = 1, like:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:1];
```

then get the NSDate the present the first moment of your next day.

> Returns the first moment date of a given date

```
- (NSDate *)startOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)date
```